# Mocha Tests Running Before Docs Defined in Before Block Are Done

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I am creating some mocha tests for my Node app. In my test, before retrieving some docs that are created, I need to first create those docs in the database. Then I retrieve them and run some tests on the results.

The problem I'm noticing is that even though I've included the function that needs to run to create the docs in the first `before()` block, and even though I'm awaiting the result of the doc creation function, my tests run BEFORE the docs are finished being created. It seems the `before()` block doesn't do quite what I think it does.

How can I rectify this to ensure the doc creation has finished BEFORE the test checks run?

```
const seedJobs = require('./seeder').seedJobs;

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(`${url}${dbName}${auth}`);

describe("Seeding Script", async function () {
  const testDate = new Date(2019, 01, 01);
  let db;
  before(async function () {
    await seedJobs(); // This is the function that creates the docs in the db
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.connect(async function (err) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        if (err) return reject(err);
        try {
          db = await client.db(dbName);
        } catch (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
        return resolve(db);
      });
    });
  });
  // Now I retrieve the created doc and run checks on it
  describe("Check VBR Code Update", async function () {
    let result;
    const jobName = 'VBR Code Update';
    this.timeout(2000);
    before(async function () {
      result = await db.collection(collection).findOne({
        name: jobName
      });
    });
    it("should have a property 'name'", async function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("name");
    });
    it("should have a 'name' of 'VBR Code Update'", async function ()    
      expect(result.name).to.equal(jobName);
    });
    it("should have a property 'nextRunAt'", function () {
      expect(result).to.have.property("nextRunAt");
    });
    it("should return a date for the 'nextRunAt' property", function () {
      assert.typeOf(result.nextRunAt, "date");
    });
    it("should 'nextRunAt' to be a date after test date", function () {
      expect(result.nextRunAt).to.afterDate(testDate);
    });
  });
  // Other tests
});
```

Comment: What db client are you using?

Comment: Details have been added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing promises and async together which is not needed. The Nodejs driver [supports async/await](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/reference/ecmascriptnext/connecting/) so rather keep it consistent.

I cannot see the `seedJobs` function but assume it works as expected. I suggest you update the `before` function as per the example below.

You also have an error initializing the date, the format should be:

```
const testDate = new Date(2019, 1, 1);
```

See the below init of mongodb client and use of await:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

const config = {
    db: {
        url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
        database: 'showcase'
    }
};

describe("Seeding Script",  function () {
    const testDate = new Date(2019, 1, 1);

    let db;

    seedJobs = async () => {
        const collections = await db.collections();
        if (collections.map(c => c.s.namespace.collection).includes('tests')) {
            await db.collection('tests').drop();
        }

        let bulk = db.collection('tests').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

        const count = 5000000;
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            bulk.insert( { name: `name ${i}`} );
        }

        let result = await bulk.execute();
        expect(result).to.have.property("nInserted").and.to.eq(count);

        result = await db.collection('tests').insertOne({
            name: 'VBR Code Update'
        });

        expect(result).to.have.property("insertedCount").and.to.eq(1);
    };

    before(async function () {
         this.timeout(60000);

        const connection = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(config.db.url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

        db = connection.db(config.db.database);

        await seedJobs();
    });

    // Now I retrieve the created doc and run checks on it
    describe("Check VBR Code Update", async function () {
        let result;
        const jobName = 'VBR Code Update';
        this.timeout(2000);

        before(async function () {
            result = await db.collection('tests').findOne({
                name: jobName
            });
        });

        it("should have a property 'name'", async function () {
            expect(result).to.have.property("name");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I will try this, but just to clarify, what, in your mind, is the actual issue? Because, from what I can tell, the issue is with the order in which Mocha runs things. So how does your answer address that? Just wanting to be clear. Thanks.

Comment: You are wrapping the before with a returning Promise and also using async and all gets rather confusing to follow. `await client.db(dbName);` does not return a promise etc. I would either use the promises and include mocha's `done()` callback to indicate when the before should end, or stick to async/await. Personally I prefer to now stick with asyc/await. Take look at done() callback use [here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)

Comment: @Muirik I know you posted another question about the sync nature of before - I have updated the answer here to include a large bulk-loading of 5m records which takes about 30s on my machine, to demo how the tests will wait for `before` to complete. Check your loading script to make sure nothing is running async and returning before complete.

Comment: In the end I got it to work using something Mocha provides when you need to do some set-up first: 

`setTimeout(function() {
  // do some setup

  describe('my suite', function() {
    // ...
  });

  run();
}, 5000);`