# How to restore mongo in chai mocha

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

So I want to restore mongo database before tests begin.
I do this way:

```
const app = require("../app");
const chai = require("chai");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require('../models/users');
const Region = require('../models/regions');
const testUsers = require('../testdata/users.json');
const testRegions = require('../testdata/regions.json');

describe('Restoring database', function () {
    before(function(done) {
        var promises = [
            User.deleteMany().exec()
            ,Region.deleteMany().exec()
        ];
        console.log('Cleaned database');
        done();
    });

    before(function(done) {
        testUsers.users.forEach(element => {
            var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
            element._id = new ObjectId(element._id);
            var newUser = new User(element);
            newUser.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("err:",err);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log('Users added');
        done();
    });

    before(function(done) {
        testRegions.regions.forEach(element => {
            var newRegion = new Region(element);
            newRegion.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("err:",err);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log('Regions added');
        done();
    });
```

`testdata/users.json` and `testdata/regions.json` are simple json files including key/pair values.

Does this look good?
When I run

```
npm test
```

It does not give any error. And in the console I see this:

```
Restoring database
Cleaned database
Users added
Regions added
```

But when I look in database I get different results.
Sometimes everything looks good. All the rows are in the collections.
Sometimes a few rows are missing in one of the collections.
Sometimes one of the collections is empty.

This is a very strange behaviour.

I also tried to add in the variable "promises" each of the "newUser" and "newRegion" instead of executing them directly.
But I still get these strange results.

Whats the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to `done()` being called **before** the async statements/promises have completed.

Either use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or use Promises and only call `done()` when your async statements/promises have completed.

For example:

No `done()` call as we using `await` statements which will wait till each statement completes before continuing:

```
before(async function() {
    let userResult = await User.deleteMany();
    let regionResult = wait Region.deleteMany();

    console.log('Cleaned database');
});
```

Or use `done()` with promises:

```
   before(function(done) {
        User.deleteMany()
           .then(result => {
              console.log('Cleaned database');

              done();
           });
    });
```

The syntax in your before example is not adding Promises at all, it is simply adding those functions to an array:

```
    var promises = [
        User.deleteMany().exec()
        ,Region.deleteMany().exec()
    ];
```

Take a look at the following related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58922784/62282) to help.